# sql updating hour only

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-update

i have the data like this:

```
DATE_CLOTURE
------------
2013-11-29 16:12:11.000
2013-11-29 08:12:11.000
2013-11-29 13:12:11.000
2013-11-29 11:12:11.000
```

what i expected

```
DATE_CLOTURE
------------
2013-11-29 18:00:00.000
2013-11-29 12:00:00.000
2013-11-29 18:00:00.000
2013-11-29 12:00:00.000
```

my litte idea is:

```
UPDATE [Soft8Exp_Server_44].[dbo].[LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL]
   SET [DATE_CLOTURE] = ??? here set 12

 WHERE datepart(hour,date_cloture) > 6 and datepart(hour,date_cloture) <= 12 

 UPDATE [Soft8Exp_Server_44].[dbo].[LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL]
   SET [DATE_CLOTURE] = ??? here set 18

 WHERE datepart(hour,date_cloture) > 12 and datepart(hour,date_cloture) <= 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution but it's perhaps not clean (i like working with cast but it's perhaps not the most efficient)

It's sql server 2008 compatible (i think date was not existing before)

```
select CAST(rtrim(cast(getdate() as date))+ ' 16:00:00' as datetime)
```

I use date on my getdate to only keep the date, i use the rtrim to cast as char (it's bad, but quickly written) then i concatenate my date to a datetime.

Instead of 2 update, do only one with a case when, it's better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This would remove the time part of the dates:

```
UPDATE LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL
SET date_cloture = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_cloture))
```

(Found the method [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/10/sql-server-retrieve-select-only-date-part-from-datetime-best-practice/))

Then you can do another DATEADD to put the hours that you want in the rows that you want:

```
UPDATE LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL
SET date_cloture = CASE 
    WHEN datepart(hour, date_cloture) > 6
      AND datepart(hour, date_cloture) <= 12
      THEN DATEADD(hh, 12, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_cloture)))
    WHEN datepart(hour, date_cloture) > 12
      AND datepart(hour, date_cloture) <= 18
      THEN DATEADD(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_cloture)))
    END
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cd40/1)</kbd>